# Timepicker save 12h to 24 hours Format

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

I'm having problem on saving the value of the Time Picker of Kendo to 24 Hours Format , Timepicker shows `"HH:mm tt"` format but i want to convert it to `"HH:mm:ss"` , I use Time Span for my drowdown list

Sample Codes

```
String clientShiftId = formCollection["clientShiftId"];
            String clientId = formCollection["clientId"];
            String dateShift = formCollection["dllShiftDay"];
            String startTime = formCollection["txtStartTime"];
            String endTime = formCollection["txtEndTime"];
            var stayHere = formCollection["stayHere"];

            Client_Customer_Position_Shift clientCusPosShift = new Client_Customer_Position_Shift();
            try
            {

                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientShiftId) || clientShiftId == "0")
                {
                    client.Client_Customer_PositionID = Convert.ToInt32(clientId);
                    clientCusPosShift.Day_LookID = Convert.ToInt32(dateShift);
                    DateTime parsed = DateTime.ParseExact(endTime.Trim(), "hh:mm tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    client.EndTime = parsed.ToString("HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);  <------- Line of Error 
DateTime parse = DateTime.ParseExact(startTime.Trim(), "hh:mm tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    client.StartTime = parse.ToString("HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);  <------- Line of Error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't parse it as a `TimeSpan` if it has an AM/PM designator. You could use:

```
DateTime parsed = DateTime.ParseExact(endTime.Trim(), "hh:mm tt",
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// If you need a string
client.EndTime = parsed.ToString("HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// If you just need a TimeSpan
client.EndTime = parsed.TimeOfDay;
```

I'm assuming that the value you get will always *be* in the invariant culture? You should also consider using `DateTime.TryParseExact` instead of `ParseExact`, in order to detect invalid input more cleanly.

Note the "hh" instead of "HH" when parsing, by the way - you'll receive 11pm as "11:00 pm" rather than "23:00 pm". Also note how I'm using a local variable for the intermediate value - I would recommend that rather than repeatedly setting the same property (`client.EndTime`) which could lead to confusion when debugging.

(As an aside, you could also use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library for this, which has a separate `LocalTime` type, which is more appropriate here as you don't have a date. I wouldn't suggest it for *just* this case, but if you're doing other date/time work in the app you may find it useful.)

Comment: Thank you sir but im having error at client.EndTime = parsed.ToString("HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 

Cannot Convert source type 'string' to target type 'System.TimeSpan'

@Jon Skeet

Comment: Actually client.EndTime is the TimeSpan here sir

Comment: @EnriqueGil: Then the code in your original question makes no sense, as you're assigning a string to `client.EndTime` in the second line. You said you wanted to convert the value to a format of `HH:mm:ss` - if you just want a `TimeSpan`, that again makes no sense. If you *really* just want a `TimeSpan`, use my first line but then take the `TimeOfDay` property. Personally I don't like using a `TimeSpan` for a time of day anyway, but that's a different matter.

Comment: hmmm. . . because it is in save controller

Comment: what should be the best approach here @Jon Skeet

Comment: Well we don't have nearly enough context to answer that question. I've shown you how to get a 24-hour string format, and I've explained how to get a `TimeSpan` instead. If you want advice on a *design* level, I suggest you ask a new question with more context - it's inappropriate to use a comment thread to pursue that.

Comment: @EnriqueGil: Not really - you're now talking about "line of error" but not what the error was. It sounds like you possibly *do* just want a `TimeSpan`, but you need to set the format for your dropdown.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36079/discussion-between-enrique-gil-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: @EnriqueGil: No, I'm afraid I haven't got time for chat now. I've edited my answer to show *either* formatting to a string *or* fetching the `TimeSpan`; that covers the "converting the input data into whatever form you want" question - if you have a separate question, then *ask it as a separate question*.

Comment: the error as i said is Cannot Convert source type 'string' to target type 'System.TimeSpan'
the format of the dropdown is "HH:mm tt" but i want to save it in 24hours format

Comment: @EnriqueGil: Okay, so you *don't* want to convert to a string at this point - but you need to distinguish the value you're using for display from how you're saving it. Use the `TimeOfDay` property as I've shown in my answer - and ask another question about the saving part. (Personally I would recommend *against* saving it as a string at all... use an appropriate data type in your database.)